# Yii2 hasMany() and via() or viaTable() activeRecord methods syntax

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I'm trying to create a relational query to use junction table using Yii2 ActiveRecord methods.
Table favorites contains user_id and object_id cols. The col object_id links to user.id and col user_id links to user.id. It's 1 to N relation.

I want to create relation like this:
user.id -> favorites.user_id && favorites.object_id -> user.id.

```
class User extends ActiveRecord
{

public function getFavorites()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Favorite::className(), ['user_id' => 'id' ]);
}

public function getFavoriteUsers()
{
    return $this->hasMany($this::className(), ['user_id' => 'object_id', 'subject_id' => Subjects::PROFILE ])->via('favorites');
}

public function getFavoriteUsersViaTable()
{
    return $this->hasMany($this::className(), ['user_id' => 'object_id', 'subject_id' => Subjects::PROFILE ])->viaTable('{{%favorites}}', ['object_id' => 'id']);
}


}
```

But I'm getting null when I'm trying to fetch favorite users.

Answer (score 2):

```
   /**
     * relation user.id -> (1 to N) favotites.user_id
     *
     * @return Favorites[]|null
     */
    public function getFavorites()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Favorite::className(), ['user_id' => 'id' ]);
    }

    /**
     * relation user.id -> (1 to N) { favotites.user_id | favorites.object_id } -> (1 to 1) user.id
     *
     * @return Users[]|null
     */
    public function getFavoriteUsers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::className(), ['id' => 'object_id'])->via('favorites');
    }

    public function _getFavoriteUsers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::className(), ['id' => 'object_id'])
            ->viaTable(Favorite::tableName(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
    }
```